# Get category ID after creating a category - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, function, categories

I am creating two categories within my `functions.php` file when my Wordpress theme is activated like so:

```
/**
 * @desc Create categories on theme activation
 **/
function create_my_cat () {
if (file_exists (ABSPATH.'/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php')) {
    require_once (ABSPATH.'/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php'); 
    if ( ! get_cat_ID( 'Work' ) ) {
        wp_create_category( 'Work' );
    }
    if ( ! get_cat_ID( 'Blog' ) ) {
        wp_create_category( 'Blog' );
    }
}
}
add_action ( 'after_setup_theme', 'create_my_cat' );
```

If the two categories Work and Blog do not already exist, create them but if they do already exist, do nothing.

How do I get the ID's of those two new categories when they are created/if they already exist? I need to store them as two separate variables ($work & $blog) if possible so I can reuse them within the same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From wordpress [manual](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_category)

```
wp_create_category( $cat_name, $parent ):
```

- Returns 0 on failure, category id on success.
- If the category already exists, it is not duplicated. The ID of the
  original existing category is returned without error.

> ```
> $work = wp_create_category( 'Work' );
> $blog = wp_create_category( 'Blog' );
> ```

I tested the behavior and works exactly as written in the instructions

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are variables function specific? As in, I have used your code and it works however I'm trying to use the $work variable within another function but that doesn't work...Confused! Can you use variables within arrays?

Comment: Variables are local, if you want them to be global, add `global $work;` at the beginning of all functions that needs variable $work, including create_my_cat() function. And of course, you can save them in the array and use something like `global $myArray;`